# K3D (Kubernetes) Registry Fails with No Such Host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3d

It appears the default K3D registry commands are broken.

```
k3d registry create test-registry.localhost --port 23456
k3d cluster create test-cluster --registry-use k3d-test-registry.localhost:23456
docker tag nginx:latest my-cluster.localhost:12347/mynginx:v0.1
docker push k3d-test-registry.localhost:23456/mynginx:v0.1
```

Fails with:

```
The push refers to repository [k3d-test-registry.localhost:23456/mynginx]
Get "https://k3d-test-registry.localhost:23456/v2/": dialing k3d-test-registry.localhost:23456 with direct connection: resolving host k3d-test-registry.localhost: lookup k3d-test-registry.localhost: no such host
```

The expected behavior is that the host is aliased to localhost:23456 and can handle the pushed image. A better experience if that can't happen is that there is an error when trying to create the registry or mapping the host.

System:

- Mac (M1)
- Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour and am interested in a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this playing with k3d

On Mac: Sudo edit your /etc/hosts file and add this entry for the name of your registry cluster name:

```bash
127.0.0.1 k3d-test-registry
```

and save that file, then try to push to it again

Step 2 from:
https://k3d.io/v5.1.0/usage/registries/#preface-referencing-local-registries